# how to set corner radius for top left and top right of a UIView on tableview Custom Cell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

**ViewController.swift**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mycell") as! CustomTableViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    cell.nameLbl.text = "\(adminNmaes[indexPath.row])"
    cell.aboutLbl.text = "\(aboutarray[indexPath.row])"
    if indexPath.row == 0
    {
        cell.view1.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft,.topRight], radius: 10)
       // tableView.reloadData()
    }

    return cell
}

extension UIView {
func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

i setup custom cell class using autolayout and used an extension to apply cornerradius for only 1st cell. i aslo want to give corner radius for bottom left and bottom right for the footer and also give it a padding of 10. any help is appreciated.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[image]As of iOS11, CALayer has property maskedCorners:

`var maskedCorners: CACornerMask { get set }`

In your case you would use:

`cell.contentView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]`

This masks the top left and right corners to whatever cornerRadius you've set.

Also you need to make sure that the contentView is clipping its subviews so that they can conform to the shape

`cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: could you please explain?. my issue is when i set the corner radius in cell for row index path , the 1st cell disappears and if i try to scroll it to top then only it gets appeared

Comment: @vishnu What's inside your CustomTableViewCell class an image? Also try the updated answer

Comment: i will post a picture , i have a uiview on which i have a button and 2 labels

Comment: @vishnu add your edit to the question you asked not the answer. Also you are setting your backgroundColor to clear in the question. Also try the updated answer

Comment: i added this line to my cell for row at indexpath function " 
            cell.view1.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]
            cell.view1.clipsToBounds = true"  still no change

Comment: @vishnu don't change what I gave you. Leave it as is, because what you just sent, it looks as if your masking a subview. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181775/discussion-between-vishnu-and-stefan).